# Sed replace the middle string

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, replace

I have this this String

```
22<>22
```

And i have this list

```
test
dev
too
```

The output should be like

```
22test22
22dev22
etc..
```

This is the commands i use for do that

```bash
cat list | sed 's/$/22/g' | sed 's/^/22/g'
```

##### edit

The command i use for do that

```bash
cat list | sed 's/$/22/' | sed 's/^/22/'
```

But it doesn't helpful
Because i have big list of

```
22<>22
3<>33
134423<>4
```

Comment: Take a look at sed's key `-f`

Comment: About "I have big list of" , are those strings defined in a file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to an array the list of strings that will replace to `<>`.
In a file called `list.txt` you should have:

```
test
dev
too
```

And in a file called `data.txt` you should have:

```
22<>22
3<>33
134423<>4
```

**Solution 1:**
Reading the file `list.txt` and assign its content to an array.

**Read array using bash**

```bash
export IFS=$'\n'
readarray array < list.txt
```

**Read array using zsh**

```bash
array=("${(@f)"$(<list.txt)"}")
```

Finally you have to iterate over `array` variable to get each element of the list and replace  with `sed`:

```bash
for i in ${array[@]}; do 
sed "s/<>/$i/g" data.txt
done
```

**Note:** The for loop will print the text to the stdout (in your terminal). But if you want to redirect the output to a file, you can use `>` after `done` keyword:

```bash
for i in ${array[@]}; do 
sed "s/<>/$i/g" data.txt
done > final.txt
```

*This solution will produce an output like this:*

```
22test22
3test33
134423test4
22dev22
3dev33
134423dev4
22too22
3too33
134423too4
```

**Solution 2:**
First you will have to read the file `list.txt` and assign its content to an array.
**Read array using bash**

```bash
export IFS=$'\n'
readarray array < list.txt
```

**Read array using zsh**

```bash
array=("${(@f)"$(<list.txt)"}")
```

After that you have to iterate over each line of file `data.txt` and inside that loop read each item from the array to apply the `sed` command:

```bash
while read line ; do 
for i in ${array[@]}; do 
   sed "s/<>/$i/g" <<< "$line"
done
done < data.txt
```

Or redirecting the stdout to a file:

```bash
while read line ; do 
for i in ${array[@]}; do 
   sed "s/<>/$i/g" <<< "$line"
done
done < data.txt > final.txt
```

*This solution will produce the following output:*

```
22test22
22dev22
22too22
3test33
3dev33
3too33
134423test4
134423dev4
134423too4
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution

Answer (score 1):

change `<>` to one character `|` delimiter:

```
$ sed -s 's/<>/|/g' asdf1 > asdf2
$ cat asdf2
22|22
3|33
134423|4
```

combine 2 files into one file, using same one character `|` delimiter:

```
$ paste -d"|" asdf asdf2 > combined
$ cat combined
test|22|22
dev|3|33
too|134423|4
```

split with `|`, and print in order:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $2 $1 $3}'  combined
22test22
3dev33
134423too4
```

So, in summary:

```
sed -s 's/<>/|/g' asdf1 > asdf2
paste -d"|" asdf asdf2 > combined
awk -F'|' '{print $3 $1 $2}'  combined
```

But this will only works, if there is only 1 `<>`placeholder in each line.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, assuming `list` doesn't contain `$`, `` ` `` nor `\` characters:

```
$ cat list
22<>22
3<>33
134423<>4
$ cat data
test
dev
too
$ () {print -rC1 -- ${(e)${(f)"$(<list)"}//'<>'/'$^@'}; } ${(f)"$(<data)"}
22test22
22dev22
22too22
3test33
3dev33
3too33
134423test4
134423dev4
134423too4
```

Where we pass the non-empty lines of `data` as arguments to an anonymous function. Within that function, we replace `<>` with `$^@` in the lines of `list`, so we end up with `22$^@22` `3$^@33`, and with the `e`xpand parameter expansion flag, the expansions in there are performed, where `$^@` is like `$@` (the list of arguments) except that the array expansion is `rc`/`fish`-like instead of csh-like (with `a=(1 2 3)`, `before${^a}after` expands to `before1after` `before2after` `before3after` instead of `before1` `2` `3after` with `before${a}after`).